# Building Chromium on windows throws an error message

Tags: chromium, gn

After fetching Chromium's source code, I executed the following command

```
$ gn gen out/Default
```

This results in an execution error:

> /c/src/depot_tools/gn: line 8: exec: python3: not found

What's the problem and how to solve this error?

Comment: It's quite clear, `gn` is unable to find `Python3` which is bundled with `depot_tools`. Looks like you have not followed all the instructions properly. You should follow the instructions specified at `Install depot_tools`

Comment: Also looks like you are using `git bash` to do so. Better open `Visual Studio Command Prompt` and then run this command `set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0` and execute that command again

Comment: thanks! thanks to u i solved it,, but I got an other !!

Comment: $ gn gen out/Default
/c/src/depot_tools/gn: line 8: exec: python3: not found

Comment: Use this command from command prompt window: `gn clean out\Default` then try `gn gen out\Default` again.